# How can I change the color of a specific date in calander view

Tags: android

Let's assume on 3rd of May there's an event, and I want my app to change the color of this date to remind me with this event.. thanks

```
{
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,
                int month, int day) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Comment: i think you have to make custom calendar i have the sample if you want

Comment: i'll be happy to get it